# cloud9 installation doesnt let me edit /python/ops/seq2seq.py

Tags: python, tensorflow, cloud9-ide

In a local installation I added a return value of model_with_buckets() in /python/ops/seq2seq.py. Works like magic (locally). Then I upload both my model-files (/models/rnn/translate/seq2seq_model.py) as well as my new /python/ops/seq2seq.py to cloud 9.

But then when I run it the system complains it's requesting 3 return values but only getting 2 (even though the new seq2seq.py should return 3). Does c9 cache those ops-files somewhere?

Thx

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to update the seq2seq.py in the python library.

```
.../python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py
.../python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py
```

The location should be depend on your system.

Please search them first:

```
$ find / -name "seq2seq.py"
```

Then, replace them with your modified version.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found it. While after installing on c9 there is the ~/workspace/tensorflow-path with all the files (incl. the ops-files) in them, actually there also is the /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow-path.

When running from the ~/workspace/tensorflow-path the ops-files are still loaded from the /usr...-path. So when editing my python/ops/seq2seq.py in the /usr..-path all is fine and I get access to my third return-value.